# Can I import Windows 8.1 Minecraft worlds to Windows 10?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm talking about Java to Java, and if I can't directly transfer how to format the files?

Answer (score 1):

The operating system doesn't have anything to do with the format of the worlds. It depends on the version of the game you are transferring from and transferring to.

**create a backup before using the feature I'm about to explain.**

A feature called "optimize world" was added in Minecraft 1.13 and it can convert older worlds to the new format. I'm not sure which versions are supported by this feature though. To optimize a world, go into the singleplayer menu, select a world, click edit and click optimize world.

Comment: The Minecraft version has nothing to do with the operating system version, so the last paragraph is irrelevant to the question.

Comment: @FabianRöling I never said that it did. I'm trying to explain that it doesn't matter which Windows version you are exporting the save files from because Java (the language Minecraft was written in) is cross-platform. The only important factor is the version of the game the op if transferring from and the version they are transferring to.